# How to make CPTs responsive when on ipad?

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having trouble with my cpts in the ipad format. I have a row of 3 cpts on desktop and when on ipad they go down to 2 and locate themselves on the left hand side of the screen.

Here is the link to the page: https://athleteperks.co.uk/your-perks/

It would be great if someone could inform me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The grid framework keeps its full 12 column grid down to 768px, and switches to its single column grid at 767px. There's a couple issues here.

The `w-col-3` left column (the filters) has a px width specified on it inline, which overrides the default 25% set by the grid framework.

```
element.style {
    width: 290px;
}
```

Remove that, and the left column now sits correctly to the left. If you don't know what is setting that inline style you could override it, but this is messy and not ideal.

```
.filter-bar.w-col-3 {
    /* overrides an inline style set by I don't know */
    width: 25% !important;
}

@media ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .filter-bar.w-col-3 {
        /* overrides an inline style set by I don't know */
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

The other problem is your floated perks have a `w-col-4` on them, which specifies a 32% width, but also a 10px margin-right which is added on top of the 32%. This causes it to hold one less div than is expected. The margin-right looks good, so keep that. You'll need to add a custom width onto it.

```
.perk.w-col-4 {
    width: calc( 32% - 10px );
}
```

And now those respond as your grid expects them to.

Comment: I can't find in my style sheet?  -  element.style {
    width: 290px;
}  @pants

Comment: It's not in your style sheet. It's inline. Like `<div class="w-col-3" style="width:290px;">`. Either it's hard coded into a template, or some javascript is adding that.

Comment: I can't seem to fix the problem

Comment: Did you try putting the `.filter-bar.w-col-3` override into your stylesheet? That should force it to work.

Comment: yeah i tried the following: .filter-bar.w-col-3 {
    /* overrides an inline style set by I don't know */
    width: 25% !important;
}

@media ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .filter-bar.w-col-3 {
        /* overrides an inline style set by I don't know */
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a0v32a51/1/ This recreates your problem, and implements my solution at the bottom of the css. Try commenting out my solution and rerunning it to see how it matches your problem. Play with the window width to see responsiveness. If this isn't working then it's something to do with how the css is getting onto the page.